# android capture all app events

Tags: android, analytics

I want to capture all events of a user including button clicks, I am using google analytics , its giving correct data, but i want more accurate data , where we can handle app events  in program and sent to the server. 
For example , I have a profile page activity, if user visits the page once, the count is 1 and then its get incremented next time, when user closes the app, count again becomes zero, like that i want for every activity , is it possible ?is there any sdk for that ?

please excuse me if my question is irrelevant. But give me some suggestions.

Comment: I don't know that you have heard about it or not. But I have used it in my project. I would suggest you to use https://www.swrve.com/